# How to replace array elements with another given array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a function that completely override the original array.

```
function putDatainthis(arr) {
    //....some ways to get data
    arr = [data,data,data...]; //this just reassigns arr = to new array original that was passed as reference hasn't been modified.
}
```

//so right now only way i can think of is this:

```
function putDatainthis(arr) {
    var data = [3,4,6,2,6,1];
    arr.length=0;
    data.forEach(function(e){
      arr.push(e);
    });
}
```

but i want to know can it be improved or is there more native way.

Comment: basically i want replace function

Answer (score 3):

The **[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** function is what you are looking for, this is your way to go:

```js
function putDataInThis(arr) {
  var data = [3, 4, 6, 2, 6, 1];
  arr.length = 0;

  arr.splice(0, arr.length, data);
  return arr;
}

alert(putDataInThis(["h", "g"]).join(","));
```

**Explantation:**

In the following `arr.splice(0, arr.length, data)` statement, we used `splice()` function with the following parameters:

- `0` the beginning index for the replacement.
- `arr.length` as the number of elements to replace.
- And `data` is the list of new values to put in our array.

Read **[Array.splice( ): insert, remove, or replace array elements](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/re16.html)** for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [jquery merge](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/).

```
function putDatainthis(arr) {
    var data = [3,4,6,2,6,1];
    $.merge(arr, data);
}
```

Comment: i will be using it in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
function putDatainthis(arr) {
    var data = [3,4,6,2,6,1];    
    var concat_array = data.concat(arr);
}
```

Comment: arr has not changed in this example